# IBM Watson Assistant: Problems in login with ConversationV1

Tags: ibm-cloud, credentials, watson-assistant

I need a username and password for my application.
I'm use watson-developer-cloud==1.0.2

I can't find the information on the new platform.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the portal, then to the Watson Assistant service page. Click on credentials to obtain them. If you have username / password, then use them. If you have IAM with an API key, use "apikey" as username and the key as password.

[Details are in the IBM Watson Assistant docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-services-information#services-information-authenticate-api-calls).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Watson Assistant portal.
[image]

Click on the three dots on the skills card.
[image]

Get the API Key from there.
[image]

To connect to that instance, use the username apikey and the password that you got from the page.